# Error Installing any module using pip, but easy_install works

Tags: python, sockets, pyopenssl

I get this error whenever I try to install any module using pip, but easy_install work perfectly. I have no proxies configured in my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.
Previously it was working fine, just dnt know, how it stoped working suddenly.

This is error i get, while running `sudo pip install <any_package_name>`:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 345, in prepare_files
    functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 290, in _walk_req_to_install
    more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 415, in _prepare_file
    req_to_install, finder)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 376, in _check_skip_installed
    finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, self.upgrade)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 425, in find_requirement
    all_versions = self._find_all_versions(req.name)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 349, in _find_all_versions
    index_locations = self._get_index_urls_locations(project_name)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 323, in _get_index_urls_locations
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 789, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 878, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 476, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 367, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 762, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/tmp/tmpOA61D3/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 296, in ssl_wrap_socket
    cnx.set_tlsext_host_name(server_hostname)
AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'set_tlsext_host_name'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a potential solution [here](https://github.com/passslot/passslot-python-sdk/issues/1).  Here's the relevant quote:

"That happend because Ubuntu 12.04 (that is my server's OS) has old `pyOpenSSL` library which not accept attribute 'set_tlsext_host_name'.
For fix that, you need to add dependence `pyOpenSSL` >= 0.13.
On Ubuntu for update `pyOpenSSL` use `pip`, you also need to install `libffi-dev` and remove `python-openssl` by `apt`."

```
$ sudo apt-get purge python-openssl
$ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
$ sudo pip install pyOpenSSL
```

Let me know if this is unclear or if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: This also works for a similar issue with Centos 6.4.
The same SSL related error occurs... the solution is to install libffi-devel using yum, and then use easy_install to upgrade pyopenssl.