# pip install bs4 giving _socketobject error

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to install BeautifulSoup4 using the command `pip install BeautifulSoup4`, as per the bs documentation here:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5, and python 2.7.12

When I run the command in Terminal I get the error:

```
AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'set_tlsext_host_name'
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
In light of comments I have tried to run `sudo pip install pyopenssl` however I get the same 'socketobject' error.

Comment: pip install -U pyOpenSSL

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Same error unfortunately

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849892/error-installing-any-module-using-pip-but-easy-install-works

Comment: @saurabhbaid the other OP's question is on Ubuntu, and the solution involves apt-get, which I understand you can't use on a mac (correct me if I'm wrong?)

Comment: I am no mac user but I dont it doesn't look like your issue is specific to MAC, It looks like some of the dependent libraries like libffi-dev or PyOpenSSL are missing on your machine.

Comment: Are you using the Apple-installed version of Python? That could be your problem.

Comment: As an alternative to anaconda, have you tried using homebrew? and then ` brew install openssl` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31576259/3579910:

Try:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-openssl
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
sudo pip install pyopenssl
```

Apparently you can't vote duplicate if there is an open bounty.

Background:

> That happend because Ubuntu 12.04 (that is my server's OS) has old
>   pyOpenSSL library which not accept attribute 'set_tlsext_host_name'.
>   For fix that, you need to add dependence pyOpenSSL >= 0.13. On Ubuntu
>   for update pyOpenSSL use pip, you also need to install libffi-dev and
>   remove python-openssl by apt.

[Source](https://github.com/passslot/passslot-python-sdk/issues/1)

---

On Mac, you can get homebrew to replace the apt-get calls: follow the instructions for installing [homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19688479/3579910).

Comment: Any idea what the brew equivalent of purge is? @TemporalWolf

Comment: @tompreston I would check out this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7333289/3579910)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the *`pyopenssl` package version installed system-wide is not up-to-date*. Upgrade it:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pyopenssl
```

Or, remove it and install the latest in your virtual environment:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall pyopenssl
$ # activate virtual environment
(myvirtualenv) $ pip install --upgrade pyopenssl
```

Answer (score 1):

"That happend because your OS has old pyOpenSSL library which is does not an accept attribute 'set_tlsext_host_name'.
To fix this, you need to add dependence pyOpenSSL >= 0.13.

```
$ brew purge python-openssl
$ brew install libffi-dev
$ brew install pyOpenSSL
```

Let me know if this is unclear or if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks, but can i run apt-get on a mac?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can install Anaconda Python from: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

This installation includes BS out of the box as most of the common libraries you will use. Plus it makes library installation quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `OS X 10.12` and `python 2.7.10`

```
sudo easy_install BeautifulSoup4
sudo easy_install pyopenssl
```

They all worked fine.